# How to shared-lock a row on a SELECT that doesn't yet exist, in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, locking

Suppose that I have a operation that, in a transaction, checks for the existence of a "log" row with an ID larger (later/newer) than its own ID.  If it doesn't exists, it does some other UPDATE operation and then inserts the log ID.  If it does exist, it just inserts the log ID without the UPDATE. Something like:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN 

SELECT TOP 1 UpdateLogId
FROM UpdateLog 
WHERE SourceRecordPrimaryKey = @SourceRecordPrimaryKey
    AND UpdateLogId > @changeNumber;

-- then, only if that doesn't exist:
UPDATE SourceTable SET ... WHERE SourceTableId=@SourceRecordPrimaryKey;

-- then, in either case:
INSERT UpdateLog (UpdateLogId, SourceRecordPrimaryKey) 
VALUES (@changeNumber,@SourceRecordPrimaryKey)
```

Now if I have two concurrent processes that might be processing two different incoming operations, but the log rows for neither one yet exist, it may come to be that both processes run at nearly the same time, both check for a later log row inside a transaction, both find (since there is no row for the other to lock) that it doesn't exist, and both execute in a race condition.

Is there a common way to handle this in SQL Server so that one of these two will block the other?   It's almost like I want a shared lock on a row that doesn't yet exist, as I plan to create it later in the transaction, and I want other processes to block if they are checking for its existence. Is there a concept here that I am missing?

Comment: Do you not have a unique constraint or primary key for your log table?

Comment: Yes, UpdateLogId is the primary key...though in my check I am not just looking for the very same log row, but if *any* newer log exists for a source primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lock a row that doesn't exist, you need a key range lock, which  you can get with the HOLDLOCK or SERIALIZABLE lock hint. And to make two sessions block each other on a key or key range lock, use the UPDLOCK hint.  UPDLOCK forces U locks which block other U locks but not S locks.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

SELECT TOP 1 UpdateLogId
FROM UpdateLog with (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
WHERE SourceRecordPrimaryKey = @SourceRecordPrimaryKey
    AND UpdateLogId > @changeNumber;

-- then, only if that doesn't exist:
UPDATE SourceTable SET ... WHERE SourceTableId=@SourceRecordPrimaryKey;

-- then, in either case:
INSERT UpdateLog (UpdateLogId, SourceRecordPrimaryKey) 
VALUES (@changeNumber,@SourceRecordPrimaryKey)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I think I want to do `WITH (XLOCK,HOLDLOCK)`, as I want other concurrent runs of my first SELECT to block till I do the INSERT and commit.  UPDLOCK wouldn't be sufficient.  Right?  Or maybe UPDLOCK would be sufficient because I am only concerned with blocking the first SELECT which is another UPDLOCK?  Just want to clarify

Comment: You understand.  Select with UPDLOCK will block update and other select with UPDLOCK.

Comment: This came very close to working, except I found that it seems to lock SourceRecordPrimaryKey values beyond what I want.  For example, if the above SELECT runs with `SourceRecordPrimaryKey = 'test'` and I try to concurrently run the very same SELECT with `SourceRecordPrimaryKey = 'test2'`, it is blocked till the first transaction is done.  Is there any way to limit my lock to the WHERE clause I have provided and not beyond?

Comment: No.  Range locks just work like that.  But your locks should be short-lived.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, one method would be to explicitly define an update and table lock on the `SELECT`, which would stop the other `SELECT` from being able to read the table until the other transaction is completed.

You could replicate this with something like the below. Firstly run the below in a query window (the transaction is intentionally left open).

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
DEFAULT VALUES
GO 10

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.SomeTable WITH (UPDLOCK,TABLOCK)
              WHERE ID = 11) --An ID that doesn't exists

        PRINT N'Do UPDATE operation';
```

Then if you open a new query window and try to run a simple `SELECT` against the table, the query will hand, due to the table being locked. If you then complete the above query by running the following, the other `SELECT` will then run returning the additional row:

```sql
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
    DEFAULT VALUES;
COMMIT
```

Comment: `TABLOCK` is unnecessary, you can use `HOLDLOCK` to get a key-range lock